# Getting time in Germany - Android

Tags: java, android

How can I get the current time in Germany regardless of the location of the user and current device time?

```
    Calendar buttoncal = Calendar.getInstance();
    String tdate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM",Locale.GERMANY).format(buttoncal.getTime());
    String tday  = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE",Locale.GERMANY).format(buttoncal.getTime());


    one_date.setText(tdate.toString());
    one_day.setText(tday);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [android.text.format.Time](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html) instead as [I suggested over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16037436/1856738).

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the timezone that needs to be used:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
```

For a list of available time zones: `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`.

Note: the locale in the `SimpleDateFormat` is used to read/format strings in that locale - using a German locale, for example, will print the months / days names in German. But it has nothing to do with the time zone.

Comment: I passed TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin") but it is still giving current device time not current time in berlin/germany.

Comment: I passed TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin") but it is still giving current device time not current time in berlin/germany.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.GERMANY); 
Date date = new Date();
dateFormat.format(date);
```

You'll  get the 'date' in the format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm". Then you can use .split() to split the returned string format using space as delimiter. Something like:

```
String[] str_array = date.toString().split(" ");
String time = str_array[1];
```