# Android - Getting Europe/Berlin current time regardless of device time and location?

Tags: java, android

This is my code. I m working on TV guide app for german tv channels therefore I need to have current time in germany regardless of device time and location

```
Calendar buttoncal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
String tdate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM",Locale.GERMANY).format(buttoncal.getTime());
String tday  = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE",Locale.GERMANY).format(buttoncal.getTime());


one_date.setText(tdate.toString());
one_day.setText(tday);
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: ^@ClassStacker I think he just wanted to inform us about his cool app ;)

Comment: @ShobhitPuri No he is asking seriously, I have answered his previous question, but I have deleted mine because other person also posted the answer and he hasn't interesting my answer here is the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987235/getting-time-in-germany-android

Comment: I was just kidding. So the question is duplicate? Actually, his question is much clear on the link you gave. Hope the answer there was of some help to him.

Comment: Yes..I asked same question earlier but i didnt get the solution.I m still looking to fix the problem. any help/suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @RickyWatson please take a moment to read StackOverflow rules. You really should not post again the same question, if you didn't got the answer; also, try write more clearly what your question is and what difficulties you're having with your current code so people won't downvote or try to close your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever people recommend using `Calender` on Android, I'll come creeping out of my tiny hiding place and tell them to please consider [android.text.format.Time](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html) instead because it's simply perfect for everyday use. Much more lightweight and to the point of practical needs.

```
Time deTime = new Time("Europe/Berlin");
deTime.setToNow();
deTime.format("...");
```

For the format, see http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime. If I'd be the author, I'd not use fixed German local format, but rather be kind to all the foreigners interested in German TV and respect the device's locale, like so:

```
deTime.format("%c");
```