# Different date format results (with exactly same locales and dates) on pc and on phone? Why?

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat

I have very simple test function:

```
public static String dateToString(long date, String format) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, locale);
    return sdf.format(new Date(date));
}
```

and I pass these parameters to it:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 3); // I need to have date in May (today is april)
Locale locale = new Locale("ca", "es",""); // Catalan locale
System.out.println(dateToString(cal .getTimeInMillis(), "MMM dd"));
```

But output on pc is:

**maig 02**

and output on android phone is:

**de maig 02**

Why? I really need to get as short as possible TEXT version of month, without words like "de" or so. I used catalan local only for denomstration - the differences can be seen also on some other locales...

Comment: Because the locales are defined differently for desktop and mobile? -- Are you running the Java directly or in an AVD on your PC?

Comment: i run normal java program on pc...Ok, locales may be different on devices, also it's strange. But how to get shortest text version of month? without "de" word? I use "MMM" format to get shortest verison of month, not second shortest...

Comment: Then the answer to your question is probably that the locale is defined differently for desktop and mobile. And why not? (Unfortunately I can't judge whether both outputs make sense in this respect.) -- On Android, I recommend [`android.text.format.Time`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html) and there, it would be `%b` I guess?

Comment: well locales are definitely SAME on pc and device, as I explicitely define them (to catalan - see my code). But anyway - can you please provide an example of what you suggested?

Comment: I didn't refer to the _locales_ but to their _definitions_. They may well differ because, well, a mobile device typically has a smaller screen? -- Note that `android.text.format.Time` is only available on Android. For a [short example see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16037436/1856738).